# How can I make sure this method works with its subclasses?

Tags: ruby

I have a simple pair of classes that looks like this:

```
class X
  include Singleton
  def base_name; self.class.name; end
end

class Y < X
  # ...
end
```

I would like invocations of `#basename` on `Y` (and on any other subclass of `X`) to return "X", and not the name of the subclass.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: If you want to have a constant return value, why not write it directly into the method?

Comment: Remark: With 'include Singleton' you may not use #new for Y or X. You must use #instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class A
  BASE_NAME = self.name
  def base_name
    BASE_NAME
  end
end

class B < A
end

A.new.base_name # => "A"
B.new.base_name # => "A"
```

Comment: Oops, yes constant. I'll delete :)

Answer (score 0):

Some meta programming:

```
class X
  def base_name; self.class.name; end
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.class_eval do 
        define_method(:base_name) do 
          self.class.ancestors[1].name
      end
    end
  end #inherited
end

class Y < X
end

p X.new.base_name
p Y.new.base_name
```

But I wouldn't use it. jtbandes answer is better in my eyes.